Replacing drywall ceiling but the vapor barrier supporting the blown-in insulation above is very thin... how should I go about this?
The drywall ceiling in two bedrooms is moldy/mildew-y (the mildew isn't everywhere on the ceiling, but rather, it takes on a particularly defined shape (straight lines, as though between trusses), as though it only occured where the area above has compromised/less insulation).
I'm looking to replace the ceilings entierly to do away with any health risk do to mold exposure.
However... my issue is this: the roof space above the ceilings has blown in insulation. It's contained by a vapor barrier, but I've been told by the previous renovation that the barrier that was used is a thinner-than-standard material, and they're co concerned that if I remove the drywall, the barrier will sag and break, releasing the insulation.
How should I approach this? Remove the ceiling in small sections and add long rungs of strapping perpendicular to the trusses in an effort to support the barrier?

How wide are the straight lines?  If just a few inches, they are probably joist/rafter shadows, cause by dust/dirt collecting there.  A simple cleaning might be all you need.

Unfortunately it's definitely mold/mildew; it's a large patch (roughly 4ft by 6 ft, it just follows a defined area, and within the area, there is less of the substance where the trusses abutt.)

Go into the attic space and shovel, rake, or vacuum the insulation from the area where you intend to replace the drywall. You can pile it in another part of the attic temporarily. Some folks vacuum it all the way out and blow it back in (or blow new in if it's also moldy.)
If you don't immediately find the source of your  moisture problem (perhaps a hole in the too-thin vapor barrier? Perhaps a small roof leak?) go hunting for it and fix it.
Then replace the substandard vapor barrier, the drywall, and the insulation in that order.
If there's no attic access and blowing in blind is the only way to access the insulation, build a barrier around the area below with plastic and zipper door access so you can contain the mess when it comes down as you remove the ceiling, and bag it up either for blowing back in or for disposal depending on its condition. Or make a small hole and vacuum out what you can reach before removing more ceiling, but I'd still suggest the plastic barrier walls.

Solid advice, thank you very much!

If there is no structural ceiling above the drywall, the simplest answer may be to just install a new layer of drywall over what's already there.

There are trusses. Also I'm looking to remedy the mold issue, and just covering it up doesn't seem to solve that issue

If there is a mold issue, there is a moisture issue that you need to solve. Otherwise, you can expect mold to return.
